# Unable to autoload constant Users, expected /app/serializers/users.rb to define it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, serialization

I am getting this error when I try to log in with facebook oauth.

```
Unable to autoload constant Users, expected /Users/cynthia/.atom/projects/Jquery_Portfolio_Project/tasks_with_JQuery/app/serializers/users.rb to define it

raise LoadError, "Unable to autoload constant #{qualified_name}, expected #{file_path} to define it" unless from_mod.const_defined?(const_name, false)
```

I think the name of the serializer is correct, could it be a missing attribute?

```
class UserSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :email
  has_many :tasks
end


class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!

  def index
    @users = User.all
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { render show: @users }
      format.json { render json: @users }
    end
  end

  def show
    @user = User.find_by(id: params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { render show: @user }
      format.json { render json: @user.tasks }
    end
  end
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable

  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :omniauthable, :omniauth_providers => [:facebook]

  has_many :tasks
  has_many :group_tasks, through: :tasks


  def self.new_with_session(params, session)
    super.tap do |user|
      if data = session["devise.facebook_data"] && session["devise.facebook_data"]["extra"]["raw_info"]
        user.email = data["email"] if user.email.blank?
      end
    end
  end

  def self.from_omniauth(auth)
    where(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid).first_or_create do |user|
      user.email = auth.info.email
      user.password = Devise.friendly_token[0,20]
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

When rendering a collection, you need to specify a serializer. Try changing your index action to this:

```
  def index
    @users = User.all
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { render show: @users }
      format.json { render json: @users, serializer: UserSerializer }
    end
  end
```